# any limitation to use "bitcoind - zapwallettxes" to reverse unconfirmed transactions?

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, unconfirmed-transactions

I read the following lines in some post about how to reverse a bitcoin transaction:

"How to stop/reverse a Bitcoin transaction without confirmations:
Run bitcoind and with -zapwallettxes.
This makes the wallet "forget" any unconfirmed transactions, thus enabling you to reuse their inputs."

My question is: Is this method only applicable to specific wallet? I use blockchain.info wallet and have some unconfirmed outgoing transactions not yet confirmed.

Answer (score 2):

> Run bitcoind and with -zapwallettxes.

*bitcoind* is the daemon version of the original Bitcoin wallet maintained by Bitcoin Core. *bitcoin-qt* would be the GUI version.

The option *-zapwallettxes* is specific for the Bitcoin Core wallet. It 'forgets' spend outputs and allows you to respend them. However this does not imply that other bitcoin nodes on the network accept a new transaction with the same (already spend in your first transaction) outputs.

*-zapwallettxes* is only affects your local wallet.

Your transaction can not be reversed. Probably the best thing to do is wait. Your transaction will confirm eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is wallet specific, not every wallet will have this command.

Comment: What wallet can use this command?